# returning bool true in linq-to-sql

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object model that contains a boolean field MyBool. I want populate that boolean with a linq-to-sql query based on whether or not the database field MyField contains data.

This is what I have:

```
var TheQuery = (from x in .....
                where .....
                select new MyModel{

                    MyBool = x.MyField.Contains(*)

                }).ToList();
```

I'm trying with the .Contain extension method but it's not working. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: "It's not working" -- in what way?

Comment: You also need parens around your query syntax (before `from` and after the `}`) before you call `ToList()`

Comment: yes,I left those out of the sample code I provided but they're there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that, according to your incomplete example,

```
MyBool = x.MyField.Contains(*)
```

should be

```
MyBool = x.MyField.Contains("*")
```

And you should have brackets around the Linq expression.

A more complete example might be useful, though.